# MongoDB query for sorting and limiting the result

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have two models User and Score

User model SCHEMA:

```
var UserSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
firstName: String,
lastName: String,
createdAt: Date,
scores:[
    {
        type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: "Score"
    }
]
});
```

My Score model SCHEMA:

```
var  ScoreSchema =  new mongoose.Schema({
score: Number,
createdAt: Date
});
```

So, basically I am trying to get all(limit:10) the scores in an sorted order of createdAt field and populating the score array as well.

Query I am using:

```
User.findOne({_id: id}).populate('scores').sort({createdAt:-1})
 .limit(10).exec(function (err, result) {
    if (err) {
        console.log(err);
        res.json({
            status: 'error',
            data: err
        })
    }
    else {
        res.json({
            status: 'ok',
            data: result
        })
    }
   })
```

I am still getting all the score and in the unsorted way.
Please help

Comment: Try `User.findOne({_id: id}).populate({
    path:'scores',
    options: {
        limit: 10,
        sort: { createdAt: -1}
    }
})....`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Node js mongoose populate limit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32207457/node-js-mongoose-populate-limit)

Answer (score 0):

Your `sort()` and `limit()` are operating on the `User` model, not the `scores` subdocument array. If you want subdocument sorting, you may want to look at [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31382656/mongoose-subdocument-sorting).