# mongoose, nodejs, sort by date in a subdocument

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have problem trying to do a sort by date of updated_at "post" (subdocument), with the code below 
i see the posts in order of creation. I need sort by date of updated.

```
var postSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    post: String,
    created_at: { type: Date, default: Date.now },
    updated_at: Date
});

var UserSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    username: String,
    password: String,
    posts: [postSchema]
});


app.get("/val",isLoggedIn, function(req, res){
    var aca = req.user._id; 
    User.findById({_id: aca},function(err, myposts){
       if(err){
           console.log(err);
       } else {
           res.render("index", {dataposts:myposts});
       }
    });
    });
```

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31382656/mongoose-subdocument-sorting

Comment: thanks for your response. Do you think is there any way to include sort in this part of the GET.
 app.get("/val",isLoggedIn, function(req, res){
    var aca = req.user._id; 
    User.findById({_id: aca},function(err, myposts){
       if(err){
           console.log(err);
       } else {
           res.render("index", {dataposts:myposts});
       }
    });
    });

Comment: Maybe you can use `User.findById({_id: aca}).sort({'posts.updated_at': 'desc'}).exec(function(err, myposts) { ... });`

Comment: Thanks I had try it, but it doesn't work. zero error but its doesn't sort it. I don't know why.

Comment: What is the version of mongoDB, mongoose you are using?

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest following,
using [$order_by](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/meta/orderby/)

```
User.findById({ $query : {_id: aca},$orderby: {updated_date: -1} })
```

In latest versions of mongoose this should work,

`User.findById({_id: aca}).sort({updated_at:-1}).exec(function(err, myposts) { ... });`

Comment: Hi, The same result it Doesn't sort. It give me the same old order of documents. The version of my mongodb 4.2.1

Comment: mongoose 5.9.11